# ¿como leer atributo name al usar dropzone js y php?

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

Hola comunidad eh buscado por todo lado, pero no encuentro solucion a esto, resulta que estoy usando dropzone.js para cargar imagenes, para ello uso un input de tipo file y con su respectivo atributo name. Pero al enviar la imagen por el form usando "POST" lo unico que obtengo es este warning:
`Warning: Undefined array key "file" Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in`

El codigo que eh estado probado:

```
    <form id="myDragAndDropUploader" method="POST" action="" class="dropzone">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit" name="subir">subir</button>
    </form>
```

Y en php recibo la informacion con

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['subir'])) {
    $img = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    echo $img;
}
?>
```

Y este pequeño script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.myDragAndDropUploader = {
        paramName: "file",
        maxFilesize: 10,
        acceptedFiles: 'image/*'
    };
</script>
```

Por mas que busco, no encuentro solucion mas que hacer envio por AJAX, pero no es lo que busco. Alguna idea?

Comment: no damos concejos mira como preguntar...

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: En el form pone: enctype="multipart/form-data", tal que te quede: <form id="myDragAndDropUploader" method="POST" action="" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Es decir no debo utilizar el input de tipo archivo en el form?